# Cant resume from suspend when screen not turned on

Tags: nvidia, suspend, 21.04

I'm having an intermittent problem resuming from sleep/suspend. One of my displays is an OLED TV and it turns itself off sometimes to power save. I think the problem happens when the system tries to resume and this display is turned off. I have another monitor connected  which turns back on but it only shows the background and I'm not able to do anything on it, I've tried hitting tab and entering my password but it seems hung and all I can do is reboot.

I am able to SSH into the machine when this happens and it seems to work fine over a shell. As an interim if there was something I could do to re-enable the display remotely that would help me too.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this but I suspect it's something to do with the GPU. I've pasted the output from journalctl.

The pertinent error seems to be `GPU state invalid after WaitForTokenInRange`

I'm on Ubuntu 21.04.
I have an Nvidia 3090 RTX GPU. Driver 470.57.02
Motherboard is an ASUS Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE

Any pointers welcome. Thanks!

https://pastebin.com/4rmKX3qC

Edit: Updated mobo BIOS drivers (WRX80) and same thing happened. New logs here, https://pastebin.com/qwVWkEAj

Comment: There's a [new kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1925843) that might be at fault. Try booting with an older kernel to see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Will give that a try.